# Python pandas how to write data from an array in excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I can not write data from an array in excel.

What parameters you need to specify functions in `DataFrame()`?

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx", sheetname="file1")
lastval = table['lastval'].values.tolist()
newval = table['newval'].values.tolist()
rm = table['rm'].values.tolist()
itog = [0, 0, 0]

for i in range(3):
    itog[i] = (newval[i]-lastval[i]) * rm[i]
    pd.DataFrame(?????)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `to_excel`. Take a look at the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).